# Mysql fulltext - How to order by relevance and date

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-text-search

I have 2 tables, parent and child.
The parent table (files) contains **1 Million** records and the child table (commands) contains **300 million** records.

```
CREATE TABLE files(
           id BIGINT NOT NULL,       
           starttime bigint NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY(id)
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;


 CREATE TABLE commands(
   file_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   rawdata VARCHAR(15997) NOT NULL,
   FULLTEXT KEY fulltxt (rawdata),
   FOREIGN KEY (file_id ) 
    REFERENCES files(id)

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

The start time is a number (unix_time).

I would like a good way to get the first 1000 records with the best relevance, order by the start_time.

something like this:

```
 select file_id, rawdata, match(rawdata) against ('some words' in boolean mode) score from files join commands on (id = file_id)
    where  match(rawdata) against ('some words' in boolean mode)
    order by score desc, starttime desc
    limit 1000;
```

This query can result with more than a million records (before the limit) and all those records need to be sorted by relevance (easy) and than by the start_time.

What is the best way to index those tables?
Is there a better way to write the query?

The response time is very important

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 300 million? Hm, we're gonna need a bigger boat.

Comment: I think you may have problems with good response time and that amount of data. There may be other products (perhaps elasticsearch) that could do this in a more straight forward way.